# C# Calling methods inside of a generic method by comparing T with MyClasses

Tags: c#, class, generics, types

I have some classes, for example:

```
class Contract
{
    public int id;
    public string num;
    public double value;
    public bool isnew;
    public bool toupdate;
    ...
}

class Attachment
{
    public int id;
    public int year;
    public int finance;
    public double value;
    ...
}
```

When I call a `MySqlDataReader.Read()` I want to call it by a generic function, that returns a `List`. Instead of making a method for every Class, I want something like this:

```
public List<T> ReadAs<T>()
{
    List<T> result;
    switch (T){
        case Contract: { result = ReadAsContract(); DoSomething1(); break; }
        case Attachment: { result = ReadASAttachment(); DoSomething2(); break; }
    }
    return result;
}

private List<Contract> ReadAsContract() {...here i make call MySqlDataReader.Read() and make list of instances...}
private List<Attachment> ReadAsAttachment() {...here i make call MySqlDataReader.Read() and make list of instances...}
```

So my questionis: is it even possible to make something like I described? Or is it better to make lots of `ReadAsMyClass` methods and call every time the exact one?

Comment: just use Dapper and do not reinvent your own micro-orm ... it has nice `DbConnection.Query<T>(...)` extension methods

Comment: Generics are the right tool where you have multiple types on which the *exact same operations make sense* in terms of those type's exposed members. When there's *nothing in common* between the types, other than an *abstract notion* that you're doing the same thing (e.g. "Reading"), it's not a good fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be useful maybe,

```
public List<T> ReadAs<T>()
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    List<T> result = null;
    switch (type.Name)
    {
        case "Contract": { 
            result = ReadAsContract().Cast<T>().ToList();
            DoSomething1(); break;
        }
        case "Attachment": {
            result = ReadAsAttachment().Cast<T>().ToList();
            DoSomething2(); break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```